# url dinâmica no ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Como eu faço para o Ajax pegar a URL atual? Pois nela estão os valores que vão para o php. Se eu fizer assim funciona

```
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/jogoteocratico/consulta.php?dificuldade=1&rodada=1",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(returnjson) {
    var i=0;
     $('#proxima').click(function exibir(){
       i++;
       document.getElementById("id_pergunta").innerHTML = returnjson[i].id_pergunta;
       document.getElementById("pergunta_jogo").innerHTML = returnjson[i].pergunta;
       document.getElementById("desafio_jogo").innerHTML = returnjson[i].desafio;
       document.getElementById("resposta_jogo").innerHTML = returnjson[i].resposta;

     });
```

Mas se eu fizer assim, não funciona:

```
$(document).ready(function mostrarPergunta(){
  var url = window.location.href;
  jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(returnjson) {
        //  for(i=0; i<returnjson.length; i++){
          //  alert(returnjson[i].pergunta);
         //}
        var i=0;
         $('#proxima').click(function exibir(){
           i++;
           document.getElementById("id_pergunta").innerHTML = returnjson[i].id_pergunta;
           document.getElementById("pergunta_jogo").innerHTML = returnjson[i].pergunta;
           document.getElementById("desafio_jogo").innerHTML = returnjson[i].desafio;
           document.getElementById("resposta_jogo").innerHTML = returnjson[i].resposta;

         });
```

Comment: Qual é a diferença entre os dois exemplos? Para usares a query string atual podes fazer `url: "/jogoteocratico/consulta.php" + location.search,`

Comment: @sergio, assim funcionou, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes usar o `location.search` para ir buscar a *querystring* do URL (`), e depois usar caminhos relativos, sem`.

Ficaria assim:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/jogoteocratico/consulta.php" + location.search,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(returnjson) {
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta colocando o código que não funcionava, mas fica aqui o adendo de que a sua resposta funcionou. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
var url = window.location.href;

jQuery.ajax({

  url: url,
  //outras coisas vão aqui

});
```

A chamada para  `window.location.href` irá pegar a url atual da página. Passe isso para a chamada do método `ajax` e você terá uma "referência dinâmica" para a url atual da página;

Comment: Eu fiz assim, dei um alert na url, ta pegando certinho, mas me retorna erro interno do servidor,

Comment: @TiagoSilveira Agora isso não é culpa da requisição feita por Ajax. Isso é algo no teu código no back-end. Agora você precisa debugar teu código pra ver o que há de errado nele.